# How to pipe into grep using backticks in Linux shell script?

Tags: sh

I am trying to execute, what I thought would be, a simple shell command within a script. When I execute this from the command prompt, it works well:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en0 | grep "IPADDR"
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
```

However, if I put this into a shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
my_command=`sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en0 | grep "IPADDR"`
${my_command}
echo $?
```

I get this error:

```
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh: line 3: IPADDR=192.168.1.10: command not found
```

So, how can I successfully execute this line within my shell script?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need root (sudo) to _read_ sysconfig files? On CentOS 6 I don't. Even if you do, you don't need `cat`, you can `sudo grep IPADDR $filename`

Comment: On the system I am using, you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you are executing the result of the command...

This line executes the code as it's between "``" that are special characters for executing the given string as a command:

```
my_command=`sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en0 | grep "IPADDR"`
```

as a result, `$my_command` is "`IPADDR=192.168.1.10`"

Then you are trying to execute it for the second time:

```
${my_command}
```

Thats why you are getting this error. There is no such a command as "`IPADDR=192.168.1.10`".

Just use `$my_command` as a result that contains your desired grepped part and skip the `${my_command}` line:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
my_command=`sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en0 | grep "IPADDR"`
echo $my_command
```

Comment: Yes and no. There is no _program_ `IPADDR=blah` hence the error -- but not all shell commands are programs, and `IPADDR=blah` is a valid command to assign a shell variable (without running anything) -- but doesn't work here because such assignments are only recognized _before_ variable (aka parameter) expansion. If you do want the assignment, `eval` will work (but `eval` in general is dangerous and should be used with great caution); in _some_ shells `declare $assignment` or `export $assignment` will treat the variable's expansion as an assignment.

Comment: I was referring to the error itself. And yes, it is a shell directive to assign a variable that can't be executed the given way. Wouldn't call it `a command` though.

Comment: [A 'simple command' is any combination of assignment(s), redirection(s), and shell-parsed 'words' which expand to an _optional_ command=utility=program name and argument(s) -- and pipelines, lists, etc. are also commands though not simple ones.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09) So a simple command, and a command, can consist entirely of one assignment.